# Handling both missing and duplicate datatime fields in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here is my code snippet

```
for file_ in allFiles: cols = ['Timestamp', 'Active_Power(in W)', 'Active_Power(in MC)', 'Apparent_Power(in VA)', 'Apparent_Power(in MC)', 'Vrms(in V)', 'Vrms(in MC)', 'Irms(in A)', 'Irms(in MC)']

df = pd.read_csv(file_,sep=',', header=None, names=cols)
print "Current file is %s" %(file_)  #Debugging statement-1
df.drop(df.columns[[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]], axis=1, inplace=True) #Drop all columns except ACTIVE POWER
print "cols %s" %(df.columns)   #Debugging statement-2
print df.head(20) # Debugging statement-3 
df0=df.drop_duplicates(subset='Timestamp', take_last=True)

print df0.head(20) # Debugging statement-4 

list_.append(df0)
frame = pd.concat(list_,axis=1)
```

Observed Output: Frame contains two fields i.e. Timestamp & Active_Power(in W) from all 4 CSV files in the source directory aligned side-by-side. So far so good.

How to remove certain rows either being duplicated and/or missing in each csv files rendering dataframe being misaligned in timestamps?

For example, @row6 there is a timestamp value missing and as a result "NaN" is being inserted appropriately. But @row10 a timestamp value is being duplicated twice in original source file and therefore removed resulting in "NaN" again, as a result the timestamp sequence got misaligned. How to deal with this issue?

Comment: Please format your post properly.

Comment: @Alex I have formatted my questions for input code

Comment: May I know the status of my question in this forum? I am new to stackoverflow. Pls help with answers..